# tikz trees: how to move a child node of a tree to the top level?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

My latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing} 
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % draw a tree
    \tikz [grow'=up, binary tree layout, nodes={circle,draw}]
      \node {9}
      child { node {8}
        child { node {6} 
          child { node {1} }
          child { node {2} }
        }
        child { node {7}
          child { node {3} }
          child { node {4} }
        }
      }
      child { node {5} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In the output, node 5 is at the same level as node 8

[image]

In my expected output, node 5 should be at the top level with nodes 1, 2, 3 and 4.

[image]

How can I move node 5 to the top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is extremely straightforward if `forest` is an option.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle, draw, l sep'+=2pt, grow'=90, edge+=blue, fill=blue, text=white, font=\sffamily, child anchor=parent, parent anchor=children},
  for leaves={tier=leaf},
  [9 
    [8
      [6
        [1]
        [2]
      ]
      [7
        [3]
        [4]
      ]
    ]
    [5]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forest tree with leaves on single tier]

Following Zarko's comment, I noticed that only some children's edges are drawn from a common point on the parent. If you don't want this, you can remove `parent anchor=children` and/or `child anchor=parent` or apply the option(s) more selectively.

[image: without specified child/parent anchors]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={circle, draw, l sep'+=2pt, grow'=90, edge+=blue!50!gray, fill=blue!50!gray, text=white, font=\sffamily, inner sep=1.5pt,},
  for leaves={tier=leaf},
  [9 
    [8
      [6
        [1]
        [2]
      ]
      [7
        [3]
        [4]
      ]
    ]
    [5]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

If `forest` isn't an option, let me know and I can delete this.

Comment: This is of course an option, I would switch to this package if it is hard in tikz trees

Comment: +1! , bur I would dropout options `child anchor=parent, parent anchor=children`. To my taste the result than is nicer :-)

Comment: @Zarko I agree, but this was the style of the 'expected output' as opposed to the current output of the OP's code. I don't much line common child anchors where the parent has a drawn shape like this. It looks a bit weird. For that matter, I'm not keen on the colouring either. (But that's partly because I didn't faff with the shade - the blue in the OP's question is better, I think.)

Comment: @Zarko Actually, I just realised the example in the question only does that for some levels. Huh. Thanks.